# Scripting/Python/Defining file corruption

Tags: python, directory, scripting

Hello dear Overflowers,

I will give you a short introduction to my "problem". The NEED TO KNOW stuff you can find below

I am a first semester IT student and am currently learning python an my own.
To get hands on experience, I got myself a Job as IT Trainee since in university you only learn math for the first year or two.

At the company I am employed my job is to verify files from a Servercrash they had.
I Basically sit there and click hyperlinks, checking if the files are intact/accessable.
I asked my IT boss wether I could spend my time writing a script for the task instead of simply clicking through 1.5 million files, amounting up to 550 GB of Data.

He enthusiastically agreed and now I am trying my best to learn python in my sparetime and testing out code while at work.

NEED TO KNOW:
I have a Directory with 1.5 million files and Data amounting up to 550GB.
In this directory one can find all sorts of files. pdf's, doc's docx, xml, dtd, you name it.
I need to write a script that goes through all the sub-directories and and files, opening them, closing them and if they cannot be opened, "mark" them and write the path in a sperate directory.
I got to the point that I can list all files, but my script can access the files and does not register a error while opening the corrupted files.

I'm told it's ugly but does it's job. I'm new to programming in general so this is my first 'proper' program.

Here's my script:

```
import os
import sys

def traverse_and_log(path = "", dumpPath = ""):
    print("entering function")
    f = open("", "w+")
    for root,dirs , files in os.walk("", topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            full_fname = os.path.join(root, name)
            print(full_fname)
            try:
               with open(full_fname, "r+"):
                    pass
               f.write("OK:{}\n".format(full_fname))
            except:
               f.write("NOT OK: {}\n".format(full_fname))
    f.close()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    traverse_and_log()
```

So how do I define an error in a file ? 
Is there an aspect that any corrupted file has incommon with others corrupted files that I could 'target' with code ? 
There must be thousands of ways a file can fail and be corrupted. I need help finding a way how to define a corrupted file.

Comment: did you try to run it on an example subset of your files? what were your error messages/problems?

as you can see, i myself am quite new here (and to python) but i wrote some bit of code that does something very similar for text files (pdf, epub, docx, etc). so while I am not sure i can fix your code, maybe if you have a specific problem i **may** have an idea or 2

Comment: I got the script running, but my script does not define what a corrupted file/failure is. Since I have all types of files with all sorts of possible errors/reasons why they cannot be opened, I am a bit lost. For now he can somehow 'open'/access all files and does not see a corrupted file. Is the file corrupted anyway ? How could I check that ?

Answer (score 0):

If i am able to understand your problem, you want to maintain a log file which will let you know about the corrupt files in your iteration.

Instead of writing the the logs into file you can use "logging" package available in python to maintain logs for the corrupted files. You can do something like this:

```
            import os
            import sys
            import logging

            def traverse_and_log(path = "", dumpPath = ""):
                print("entering function")

                #f = open("", "w+")  # you don't need this 
                for root,dirs , files in os.walk("", topdown=False):
                    for name in files:
                        full_fname = os.path.join(root, name)
                        print(full_fname)
                        try:
                           with open(full_fname, "r+"):
                                pass
                           #f.write("OK:{}\n".format(full_fname))
                           logger.info("OK:{}\n".format(full_fname))
                        except:
                           logger.error("NOT OK: {}\n".format(full_fname))
                #f.close()



            if __name__ == "__main__":
                logging.basicConfig(filename=logname,
                filemode='a',
                format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                level=logging.DEBUG)
                traverse_and_log()
                logger = logging.getLogger('FILE_READER')
```

In order, the five parts do the following:

- set the output file (filename=logname)
- set it to append rather than overwrite (filemode='a')
- determine the format of the output message (format=...)
- determine the format of the output time (datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
- and determine the minimum message level it will accept
  (level=logging.DEBUG).